# How to check if a table is empty in VBA?

Tags: vba, vb6

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
if table is not empty
            do something
else 
            do something else
end if
```

The table's name is something like this "ID_RESULT_1"

Comment: What sort of table? Part of a database? What database and what database access library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `IsEmpty()` function that will return a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized.

If you want to test if a table has nothing in its cells, you'll have to loop through them to check.

I propose a function like this, that "test" the dimension (handle only 3 dim) of the table you put in and then check all cell of the table :

```
Public Function IsTableEmpty(anArray As Variant) As Boolean
Dim DimN As Integer, _
    IsEmpty As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print LBound(anArray, 1)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then GoTo DimN0
    Debug.Print LBound(anArray, 2)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then GoTo DimN1
    Debug.Print LBound(anArray, 3)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then GoTo DimN2
On Error GoTo 0
DimN = 3
GoTo Test

DimN0:
DimN = 0
GoTo Test
DimN1:
DimN = 1
GoTo Test
DimN2:
DimN = 2
GoTo Test

Test:
    Select Case DimN
        Case Is = 0
            If Not IsEmpty(anArray) Then IsTableEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        Case Is = 1
            For i = LBound(anArray) To UBound(anArray)
                If anArray(i) <> vbNullString Then
                    IsTableEmpty = False
                    Exit Function
                Else
                End If
            Next i
        Case Is = 2
            For i = LBound(anArray, 1) To UBound(anArray, 1)
                For j = LBound(anArray, 2) To UBound(anArray, 2)
                    If anArray(i, j) <> vbNullString Then
                        IsTableEmpty = False
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        Case Is = 3
            For i = LBound(anArray, 1) To UBound(anArray, 1)
                For j = LBound(anArray, 2) To UBound(anArray, 2)
                    For k = LBound(anArray, 3) To UBound(anArray, 3)
                        If anArray(i, j, k) <> vbNullString Then
                            IsTableEmpty = False
                            Exit Function
                        Else
                        End If
                    Next k
                Next j
            Next i
        Case Else
            MsgBox "It appears that your table have too many dimensions to be tested by this code!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            IsTableEmpty = False
            Exit Function
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: This checks if the variable `ID_RESULT_1` contains an empty variant. It does nothing with tables...

Comment: @Deanna : Indeed, thx for pointing it out! I write a function that should do the trick! I just hesitated between `If anArray(i) <> vbNullString` and `IsEmpty(anArray(i))`, any comments about these?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I encountered this situation recently with an Excel ListObject. Here is what I used:

```
    Public Function IsExcelTableEmpty(oExcelTable As ListObject) As Boolean
        IsExcelTableEmpty = (oExcelTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing)
    End Function
```